# Why can't I close a question just because it has a bounty?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty

This question [Free survey web application which provides easily printable single access codes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20580/101) is obviously asking for a service.  It appears to me to be completely off-topic.

I attempted to flag it as such;  SR responded

```
 Cannot close, question has a bounty
```

(or a message very similar to that).

Why should having a bounty change the requirements for a question's content?  Based on this behaviour, I could ask any off-topic, rediculous, boorish or offensive question, and it could not be closed.   That seems completely wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You can't vote to close a question while it has a bounty. I think the reasoning is that the bounty setter is trading reputation for an increased likelihood of getting answers; closing the question would be unfair since it would prevent answers.

However bounties are not an excuse to keep a bad question around. If a question clearly needs closing, flag it as “in need of moderator intervention” and explain what's going on. Moderators can't close a question while it has a bounty, but they can refund the bounty. See [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties) on the main meta for more information (errm, well, not much more).

In [this case](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/is-there-any-free-online-survey-service-which-provides-printed-single-access-cod), I've refunded the bounty and closed the question, since it's looking for a service and not for software.

Comment: "need closing, flag it ..."   That's exactly what I tried to do, and the flag attempt was rejected.  How am I then supposed to signal the moderators?

Comment: @IraBaxter Ah, flag for moderator attention, not flag to close.